# What happens when we use a nonparametric procedure (one that does not depend on the normal distribution) on a data which is normally distributed?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If most (all?) parametric procedures have a nonparametric equivalent (one that doesn’t depend on the normal distribution) then why don't just stick with nonparametric procedures for all data? That would save us the need to check if data is normally distributed in the first place. Is it a good idea?

Comment: See this link for a good discussion: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71302/power-of-a-mann-whitney-test-compared-to-a-t-test -- I'd suggest asking this question at Cross Validated instead of here, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normal-theory tests, the fact that the population is normal provides specific information that a corresponding non-parametric test cannot use. Usually, this means that the normal theory test is more powerful for normal data than is the corresponding nonparametric test.

**Power computations for normal data.** Consider a normal sample of size $n = 50.$ We wish to test
$H_0: \mu = 0$ against $H_a: \mu > 0$ at the 5% level of significance. Also, suppose $\sigma=2.$ We are interested in the power against the specific
alternative $\mu_a = 1.$ That is the probability of rejecting $H_0$ if the true value of $\mu = 1.$ (Whether we know $\sigma$ or not, the power depends on $\sigma.$ In practical situations, one often needs to guess the value of $\sigma$ in order to estimate power.)

***Power for t test:*** First, consider using the one-sample t test. There are formulas
for the power of a t test, but let's approximate power using
a simulation. We consider many datasets $(m=100\,000$ of them) of size 50 from
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=1, \sigma-2),$ test each sample to find
the resulting P-value.

We reject $H_0$ at the 5% level if
the P-value is less than 5%. So we see the percentage of times
we reject $H_0.$ The answer is that the proportion of rejections is $0.934$ so the power is 94.4%. (Simulations and computations use R.)

```
set.seed(702)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(50, 1, 2))$p.val)
pwr = mean(pv <= 0.05); pwr
[1] 0.93426
```

***Power for Wilcoxon test.*** Now, what power do we get if we use the one-sample Wilcoxon signed-rank test instead of the t test. The power decreases a little to 92.2%. The Wilcoxon test considers the center of the distribution
to be the median, but for a normal distribution, the mean and median are the same, so it is fair to compare the the two P-values. (Exact power computations for Wilcoxon tests are difficult, so simulation may be the easiest way to get power.)

```
set.seed(702)
pv = replicate(10^5, wilcox.test(rnorm(50, 1, 2))$p.val)
pwr = mean(pv <= 0.05);  pwr
[1] 0.92181
```

***Smaller samples:*** For smaller samples, the Wilcoxon test can have a greater
power disadvantage. Consider $n = 10$ and power against the alternative $\mu_a = 2.$  The t test has power 80.5% and
the Wilcoxon test has power 78.6%.

```
set.seed(703)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(10, 2, 2))$p.val)
pwr = mean(pv <= 0.05); pwr
[1] 0.80475

set.seed(703)
pv = replicate(10^5, wilcox.test(rnorm(10, 2, 2))$p.val)
pwr = mean(pv <= 0.05); pwr
[1] 0.78646
```

Finally, let look at sample size $n = 6$ and alternative $\mu_a = 4.$ Then the power is 97.0% for the t test and only 87.2%
for the Wilcoxon test. For sample sizes 5 and below, the Wilcoxon
test is essentially useless.

```
set.seed(703)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(6, 4, 2))$p.val)
pwr = mean(pv <= 0.05); pwr
[1] 0.97062

set.seed(703)
pv = replicate(10^5, wilcox.test(rnorm(6, 4, 2))$p.val)
pwr = mean(pv <= 0.05); pwr
[1] 0.87164
```

**Power for exponential data.** By contrast, now let's look at a situation with non-normal data in which the Wilcoxon test has an advantage. Suppose we have a sample
of size 15 from an exponential distribution and we want to test $H_0: \mu = 1$ against $H_a: \mu > 1,$ and get the power against
the specific alternative $\mu_a = 2$ (which is rate 1/2).

***Wrong significance level.*** The first problem with the t test, is that a test supposedly at
the 5% level actually rejects with probability about 8.7% because
for exponential data the t statistic doesn't have a t distribution.

```
set.seed(704)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rexp(15, 1), mu=1)$p.val)
pwr = mean(pv <= 0.05); pwr
[1] 0.08734
```

***Poor power for t test.*** Then for an actual mean of 2, the t test rejects with probability
only about 41%. So the t test doesn't work at all well for
exponential samples of size 15 (or even much larger samples, for that matter).

```
set.seed(704)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rexp(15, 1/2), mu=1)$p.val)
pwr = mean(pv <= 0.05); pwr
[1] 0.41033
```

***Better power for Wilcoxon test.*** For the Wilcoxon tests we need to use the corresponding *median.*
If the exponential mean is 1, then the median is $-\log(1/2)=0.693.$ (For some reason,
R uses `mu` for the hypothetical 'location' in a Wilcoxon test.)

```
set.seed(704)
pv = replicate(10^5, wilcox.test(rexp(15, 1/2), mu=0.693)$p.val)
pwr = mean(pv <= 0.05); pwr
[1] 0.70505
```